# Hello World in Crystal Lang not outputting to terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, crystal-lang

I am using the Linux subsystem with the Ubuntu distribution for Windows 10 to compile crystal code. I have created a directory which contains a text file called `Hello.cr` and placed inside of it `puts "Hello World"`. I compile and run using `crystal Hello.cr`and expected to get to my bash terminal the old greeting `Hello World`. Instead, I get no error but also no output. `crystal run Hello.cr` fairs no better. What am I doing wrong here? As an added piece of information, I am using an integrated terminal inside of VS Code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your complete `Hello.cr`. Also, does `crystal eval 'puts("hello world")'` work as expected (i.e. print "hello world") ?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt `crystal eval 'puts("hello world")'` does work as expected and prints out "hello world" to the terminal. I did not include any more info about `Hello.cr` because that's literally all the file does--print hello world. It's just a test of my setup.

Comment: Are you running the latest version of Windows 10 and WSL? If not, you might be running into the bug described here : https://askubuntu.com/a/935878

Comment: I cannot reproduce this - Windows 10 with Ubuntu, installed crystal as decribed on the homepage (added apt repo + `sudo apt install crystal`), and it works as expected. Please add more information about which version of Crystal (did you use the Windows installer? Or did you use `apt install crystal`´?) and which versions of Windows and WSL you're running (see my previous comment).

Comment: exact file and exact command lines used pleae...